# linux kernel step by step

Tags: c, linux, assembly, kernel

i know c language.my goal is to read linux kernel.so what languages should i learn(write books too) before start reading kernel  and is there any book to help reading linux kernel

Answer (score 10):

This book is a little outdated, but [Understanding The Linux Kernel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652) is an amazing reference. It will also give you a crash course in i386 features that make a lot of the kernel facilities possible (such as the MMU and how interrupts work. With operating systems, it's sometimes hard to understand where the hardware ends and the OS begins), and reference a lot of the critical source directly.

Also, look into the [LWN Kernel article index](http://lwn.net/Kernel/Index/) for more up-to-date references.

One good way to start is come up with a really simple feature that you'd like to add to the kernel and start hacking away at it. (Something I did in college was count how many times each process got preempted and export that value via the /proc file system. Taught me a lot about scheduling, /proc, the process structure, and many other facilities). Also a recommendation, do this in a VM unless you plan to reboot every fifteen minutes.

For ad hoc questions, searching Google works, or asking questions on IRC. (Respectfully, of course.)

Comment: ok.can youwrite some books about c what will help me to anderstood linux code in depth?

Comment: Knowing C in-depth, at the very least, is a pre-requisite to even begin reading Linux source. If you want to learn C, I swear by K&R's "The C Programming Language". I guess what you need to decide is what your goals are, and ask more directed questions.

Comment: so.. i want to be system programmer.i'm 15 year old.i have readen apress begininning c from novice to professional and The C Programming Language. what i can to do now?

Comment: Saying "I want to be a system programmer" is pretty generic, I'd recommend picking specific goals. Like "I'd like to change a USB driver to output buffer sizes as it's writing data", or "I'd like to verify a page of memory of a certain process" or something else specific, and then decide how to approach that problem. When you decided to become a system programmer, what specifically did you want to do? Start working on whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel is over 11.5 million lines long! It takes years to be a good programmer and you have to be one if you want to hack the Linux kernel. Taking your age and experience into account, you will most probably fail if you make that your first C project. I recommend getting your hands wet on some other cool stuffs using C. For Example, port the codes in the GreyHat Python book (debuggers, hooking, fuzzing and e.t.c) to C and add interesting features to them. If you are really into OS development, I recommend reading good books on Assembly and writing your own little real time OS. I've seen a real time OS written by a 13 year old kid so it's possible.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not so long ago there was a Linux kernel workshop at Hackerspace Brussels. You can take a look at the links on the event page https://hackerspace.be/LinuxKernelWorkshop

Answer (score 0):

I raised this question myself years ago. I've then got stuck into lines of Linux kernel source code to figure out how it works. Till now my understanding on Linux kernel is still a mix. I think the best way to understand a program is write it by yourself. To build an OS, I think this is the minimum:

- computer hardware & architecture
- assembler & compiler
- assembly
- C language

There are lots of books out there that could help you read Linux kernel piece by piece. You still have a lot of time to rewrite it yourself.